# How to handle Google Play refund events in real-time?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Does Google Play provide any refund notifications or other types of real-time notifications? This would enable me to respond quickly.

Currently, our team is using a solution where we store the purchaseToken in a database and periodically send requests to the Google Play Developer API for secondary verification, approximately once a week. However, this method is slow and not timely.